# Describing past action

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, difference, past-tense, modal-verbs

1. I would always see him coming to school late with his jeans.
2. I would always see him coming to school late with his jeans worn.
3. I would always see him coming to school late while wearing his jeans.

Which sentence is correct, and are there any possible variations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the 3 options, no 3 is the closest to correct, although you don't necessarily need the "while".

> I would always see him coming to school late, wearing his jeans.

Is probably better.

The other two options are not quite idiomatic English for what I think you mean to say.

> "I would always see him coming to school late with his jeans."

could be interpreted as "coming to school accompanied by his jeans", which doesn't make sense. It is similar to

> "I would always see him coming to school late with his sister."

The second sentence is the construction used when worn is an adjective not a verb meaning "needing repair".

> I would always see him coming to school late with his jeans needing repair.